# How to stop CMD highlighting errors red when using GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I just installed a GCC compiler on my machine (TDM-GCC). Every time I get an error message, that line is highlighted red in CMD and all the lines after are highlighted red until I close the window. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-fdiagnostics-color=never` to disable the color-output of GCC ([docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html))

However, there seems to be an issue with your terminal.